# Change content of sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am making an web app for google docs where you can the url of the doc to a SQL database over on my own site. I want to have a sidebar that let's you enter the username and password in a form with a hidden input that contains the url of the current doc.

I've had succes with everything accept for the hidden input. I know how to run functions from the sidebar's html page. My problem lies  within the function... I hope there is something like a `document.sidebar.getUi().getElementById('URLinput').value = "the url";`

I know how to get the url. I dont know how to edit the 'body' of the sidebar.

this is my code so far:

```js
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var link = doc.getUrl();



function addUrl() { //I have no idea how to do this part...
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('page');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Timklein')
    .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page')
    .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
    .setWidth(700);
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showSidebar(html);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Timklein.tk webapp</h1>
  <form action="mysite.com/adddoc.php" method="POST">
    <b>add to database...</b>
    <br>username:
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>password:
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <br>Naam van het document:
    <input type="text" size="2" name="docName">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="docLink" id="URLinput">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">

  </form>
  <script>
    google.script.run.doSomething();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

any help would be very appreciated!!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this line of code to get the input value:
document.getElementById('URLinput').value = "the url";

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the append() function to ad a script tag that runs a function on the html page that changes the input. in the function of showSidebar you put this:
`html.append("<script>addURL(theURL);</script>");` 
you make a function on the htmlpage:
`function addURL(url) {
document.getElementById('urlinput').value = url;
}`
 and you're done!